# How to emulate Keyboard and Mouse on a loced VDI

Tags: vb.net

i have a problem and can't find a solution so far.
So i thought maybe you can help me? :)

I'm working on an virtuel Citrix Client.
Everytime when i lock the VDI, the screen, the Keyboard & Mouse Input is also locked/stopped.

Is there a way in vb.net to monitor or start an KVM emulation when the VDI is locked?

I found a way to monitor, when the VDI is locked with "SystemEvents.SessionSwitch".
But so far i did not found a way to controll the Emulation of an KVM Input.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your response and my late reaction.

So i want to check on my VDI if there is Keyboard and Mouse emulated.
If not, i want to start a process (or something) which emulates an existing Keyboard and Mouse Input.